# CQWP pulling link list , when a link is clicked renders the list item rather than opening the URL itself

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, cqwp

I have a content query web part on page which i am using to pull a list of links (from a link list)to display on page. I thought clicking this link, user would be able to navigate to the link itself, but when clicked rather the List item is opened. Can anyone tell me how i can have the link to redirect to the URL beneath and not the list item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to render Links List items that redirects to the URL instead of List Item URL in [CQWP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.aspx), specify in *Presentation* tab for **Fields to display**:

> Link: URL [Custom Columns];

as shown on picture below

[image]

Comment: The picture looks like a dead  link